# Unable to convert my PayPal IPN script from http 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

my script is presently live and I have a problematic sandbox to test my amendments on and this is pissing off some of my customers. I'm better off testing on live site.

PayPal sent an email to warn us and keeps reminding me to jump to 1.1 but since June I've had bad luck trying various mixes and consulting various platforms for advise.

Below is my current PayPal.php code which links to a lot of classes which are necessary for my website.

I have tried many combinations of coding and it is evidently seen from the commented lines.

They doesn't seem to be able to work and I have run low on options.

Is there any kind good soul able to fix this? or advise me what is going wrong?

IPN always replies me a INVALID response or Error but in http 1.0 everything is fine and dandy...

```
<?php

include_once(PayPalConfig::$params[PayPalConfig::$PAYPAL_PATH]."/PayPalSettings.php");
include_once(PayPalConfig::$params[PayPalConfig::$PAYPAL_PATH]."/PayPalConstants.php");

class PayPal
{       
    private $settings;
    private $socket;    
    private $data;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param PayPalSettings $settings
     */
    public function __construct(PayPalSettings $settings, array $data)
    {
        // Store the setting which has been passed in
        $this->settings = $settings;

        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return unknown
     */
    function connectToPayPal()
    {
        // Store the URL string
        //$url = $this->settings->paypalURL;
        $url = "ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com";

        // Open a socket with paypal and send all the POSTed info as our request        
        //ORIGINAL
        //$this->socket = fsockopen ($url, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        //AMENDED - 30/06/2013
        $this->socket = fsockopen ($url, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        //FAILED AGAIN
        //$this->socket = fsockopen ($url, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

        return $this->socket;
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return unknown
     */
    function createDataForPayPal()
    {
        // create a request to paypal to verify the data we have recieved
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        // Build request string from each value in the $_POST
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value)
        {
            //Original
            //$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            //AMENDED - 30/08/2013
            $value = urlencode($value);
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        return $req;
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @param unknown_type $fp
     * @param unknown_type $requestString
     * @return unknown
     */
    function verifyWithPaypal($fp, $requestString)
    {       
        /* OLD CHUNK
        // post back to PayPal system to validate
        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        //try this NEXT? - Not tried - 20/08/13
        //$header = "POST cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ipnpb.paypal.com\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        //$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($requestString) . "\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($requestString) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        */

        // post back to PayPal system to validate
        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($requestString) . "\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ipnpb.paypal.com\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";     

        // If the send has failed, we just have to return false
        if (!$fp)
        {
            return PayPalConstants::$FAILED_TO_CONNECT;
        }
        else
        {
            // Paypal responded to our request. Store the respond
            //Original
            fputs ($fp, $header . $requestString);
            //Amended New Try Next
            //fputs ($fp, $header . $requestString . "\r\n\r\n");

            // Fetch respond string from PayPal

            while (!feof($fp))
            {
                $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

                //Writes $res to LogFile
                //$logger->write($res); 

                // Determine if the transaction has been verified with PayPal
                if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0)
                {
                    return PayPalConstants::$VERIFIED;
                }
                else if (strcmp (trim($res), "INVALID") == 0)
                {
                    return PayPalConstants::$NOT_VERIFIED;
                }
            }

        }

        //return $res;
        return PayPalConstants::$NOT_VERIFIED;
    }

    /**
     * Return the payment status 
     *
     * @return string The payment status
     */
    function getPaymentStatus()
    {
        if ($this->socket)
        {
            return $this->data[self::$PAYMENT_STATUS];
        }
    }

    function massPayment(array $payee, $environment, $emailSubject, $receiverType, $bTest=false)
    {
        // Setup sending data               
        $currency = 'USD';
        $method = PayPalConstants::$MASS_PAYMENT;
        $nvpStr="&EMAILSUBJECT=$emailSubject&RECEIVERTYPE=$receiverType&CURRENCYCODE=$currency";

        // Encode the string
        foreach($payee as $i => $receiverData) {
            $receiverEmail = urlencode($receiverData['receiverEmail']);
            $amount = urlencode($receiverData['amount']);
            $uniqueID = urlencode($receiverData['uniqueID']);
            $note = urlencode($receiverData['note']);
            $nvpStr .= "&L_EMAIL$i=$receiverEmail&L_Amt$i=$amount&L_UNIQUEID$i=$uniqueID&L_NOTE$i=$note";
        }

        // Set end point
        if ($environment != "live")
        {
            $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Live API endpoint set here
            $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
        }

        $mode = PayPalConfig::$API;
        // What mode are we using the API?
        if ($bTest)
        {
            $mode = PayPalConfig::$API_TEST;
        }

        $API_Username = PayPalConfig::$params[$mode][PayPalConfig::$API_USERNAME];
        $API_Password = PayPalConfig::$params[$mode][PayPalConfig::$API_PASSWORD];
        $API_Sign     = PayPalConfig::$params[$mode][PayPalConfig::$API_SIGN];

        // Set the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        $version = urlencode('51.0');

        // Generate the request string
        $nvpreq = "METHOD=$method".
                  "&VERSION=$version".
                  "&PWD=$API_Password".
                  "&USER=$API_Username".
                  "&SIGNATURE=$API_Sign$nvpStr";


        // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

        // Get response from the server.
        $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

        if(!$httpResponse) {
            exit("$method failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
        }

        // Extract the response details.
        $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

        $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
        foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
            $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
            if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
                $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
            }
        }

        if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
            exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
        }

        return ($httpParsedResponseAr);

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, trimming the result straight away (as opposed to just before comparison) has worked for me:

$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
$res = trim($res);

Good luck

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks. I am thinking if it is possible that this chunk of code in my code is wrong:

Comment: I am thinking if it is possible that this chunk of code in my code is wrong: 

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
                {
                    return PayPalConstants::$VERIFIED;
                }
                else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
                {
                    return PayPalConstants::$NOT_VERIFIED;
                }

should the code be looking for "1" or "0"?